# Relational Algebra: how to express the combination of aggregation and projection?

Tags: aggregate, relational-theory, syntax, relational-algebra, projection

[image]

Here I have a table, I would like to query the average salary of departments, the SQL statement should be

```
select dept_name, avg(salary) from employee
```

I try to express this SQL in relational algebra. My assumption is as follows.

[image]

You can see that `dept_name` is not wrapped by an aggregation function, which is not following the standard.

[image]

1. Is my expression correct?
2. What is the right way to express the combination of aggregation and projection?

### Reference

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Aggregation

Comment: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) PS [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: If the SQL is legal, dept_name is single-valued per group, so you can use max(dept_name) instead--in both algebra & SQL.